# Как удалить экземпляр класса изнутри

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Как удалить объект (по аналогии с оператором `del obj`) изнутри, т.е. из метода этого объекта?

Я пропобовал `del self` и `self.__del__()`, но первый просто удаляет переменную self, а второй просто вызывает метод `__del__()`, а объект остается на месте.

Comment: `del obj` не удаляет объект (эта конструкция удаляет *имя*). Что вы хотите сделать на самом деле? Какой контекст у задачи? Похоже на [ошибку XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Comment: Есть класс Bot, который обрабатывает сообщения от пользователя, в какой-то момент пользователь может завершить беседу с блоком (перехватывается исключение BotWasBlockedError), в этот момент надо удалить объект из списка ботов и удалить сам объект.

Comment: *"удалить объект из списка"* -- в чём у вас сложности с этим? Что не получается с `del L[i]` или `L.remove(x)`.